# (Jetbrains IDEs) Remap AceJump to IdeaVim insert mode

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, ideavim

I'm currently switching from VIM to PhpStorm and almost everything I've been able to configure by myself and all around I'm pretty happy with VIM support in PhpStorm but there's been one thing that I couldn't figure out how to do. And that is how to remap keybinding from plugin A to plugin B. Concretely my need is to remap **AceJump** hotkey to **space** in command mode.

Comment: If anything -- `Settings/Preferences | Keymap | Plugins`.

Comment: This isn't much of help. I have no idea, how to bind a key just in command mode. (because i want to be able to normally write spaces in insert mode)

Comment: I'm not using IdeaVim myself. But from what I remember it uses separate keymap ... so check what keymaps you have got there -- if I'm right the it will be a matter of editing shortcut in right keymap (if AceJump plugin allows customizing that shortcut in first place, of course).

Comment: Yeah, I guess it's some kind of override system. I've got an idea that i could map it via ~/.ideavirmc without any problem, but i don't know how to exactly fire the AceJump event from here.

Answer (score 2):

On your `~/.ideavimrc` add this line:

```
nnoremap <Space> :action AceAction<CR>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this for the three different mappings for AceJump by adding the following to ~/.ideavimrc

```
nmap <Space>w :action AceAction<CR>
nmap <Space>l :action AceLineAction<CR>
nmap <Space>t :action AceTargetAction<CR>
```